# Find pattern and move

Tags: bash, find

I'm wondering if anybody knows how to find a pattern and then move it to a different location.

For example,
I have many files named:

```
odbc.ini_20110630
odbc.ini_20110639
odbc.ini_20110643
etc...
```

I want to search the pattern of just `odbc.ini` and move all of them to a different folder.

I'm not too familiar with how to execute two commands at one time (piping).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
find . -name "odbc.ini*" -exec mv {} destination \;
```

This is assuming that your files are in the directory hierarchy starting at current directory `.`.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - does this destroy all the files if the directory does not already exist?

Comment: You mean the `destination` directory?  If that happens, I am afraid the answer is yes, except for the last moved file which will be named `destination`.

Answer (score 1):

if the files are all in a single directory and you don't need any recursion:

```
shopt -s nullglob
mv odbc.ini* /new/directory/
```

if you need recursion:

```
find "${dir:-.}" -type f -name 'odbc.ini*' -exec mv {} /new/directory \;
```

Another approach could be with `extglob` but i'll leave that as an exercise for the reader =]

Answer (score 1):

If all the files are in the same directory:

```
mv /path/to/source/odbc.ini* /path/to/destination
```

If you want to move files in subdirectories as well:

```
shopt -s globstar      # put this line in your ~/.bashrc
mv /path/to/source/**/obdc.ini* /path/to/destination
```